# Aws savings plan change the commitment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing, amazon-savings-plans

I was looking at the savings plan I have a doubt can any one please suggest.

If I initially go for the commitment to use 2$/hr but later I realise I must have done 6$ /hr. Is this possible ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple savings plans active at the same time. So if you start out with a conservative estimate (e.g. $2/hr) and later realize you can benefit from a higher amount, you can purchase a second savings plan to cover the difference (e.g. $4/hr for a total of $6/hr).

Answer (score 0):

We can buy additional saving plans but can cancel or modify the plan as it needs commitment.